# How to trigger an event after a Dialog resized in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.m.Dialog.

I need to trigger an event handler after the dialog is resized.

How can I register this event handler while the Dialog in SAPUI5 does not have a resize event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation [sap.m.Dialog](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Dialog/controlProperties) has a **resizable** property that allows [sap.m.Dialog](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Dialog/controlProperties) to have a **resize handler**.If you set that property to **True** you can use [sap.ui.core.ReisizeHandler](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.ResizeHandler/methods/sap.ui.core.ResizeHandler.register) to handle that event.

See the below [example](https://jsbin.com/kivixeg/1/edit?html,js,output) on jsbin as well.

```js
var oDialogResize = new sap.m.Dialog('resizableDialog', {
            title: "Resizable Dialog",
            resizable: true,
            content: [
                new sap.m.Label("label1",{text: ""}),
                new sap.m.ToolbarSpacer(),
                new sap.m.Label("label2",{text: ""})
            ],
            endButton: new sap.m.Button('resizeDialogCloseButton', {
                text: "Cancel", press: function () {
                    oDialogResize.close();
                }
            })
        });



var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
  text: 'Open',
  press: function() {
    oDialogResize.open();
  }
  
}).placeAt('content');

oButton.addEventDelegate({
     "onAfterRendering": function () {
          sap.ui.core.ResizeHandler.register(oDialogResize, function(oEvent){
            console.log("ResizeEvent");
            sap.ui.getCore().byId("label1").setText(" W:" + oEvent.size.width);
             sap.ui.getCore().byId("label2").setText(" H: " + oEvent.size.height);
          });
     }
}, this);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script 
            src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" 
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" 
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="sapUiBody">
    <div id='content'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to your dialog:

```
this.myDialog.attachBrowserEvent("resize", function(){ 
  console.log("Resize done");
});

this.myDialog.open();
```